# Sum of even numbers errors

Tags: c

I am getting the following erors:

```
1. expected = , ; before { (line 2)
2. expected { at end of input (line 12)
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "evenSum.h"

int Even_Sum(int array, int i)
{
    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if(array[i] % 2 =0)
        {
        int sum=0;
        sum += array[i];
        return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

My header file contains the line

```
int Even_Sum(int array, int i)
```

Comment: Show what is inside `evenSum.h`, probably that is the problem

Comment: A logical error is also there in array[i] % 2 =0

Comment: int Even_Sum(int array, int i)

Comment: Yeah, i see that logical error, will change it. Thanks. But I still dont know the other errors.

Comment: `int array` + `array[i]` doesn't add up. If you're passing an array of ints, change the argument type to a pointer: `int *array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you fixed all the syntax problems, are you sure you want to return as soon as you've found the first even number in the array? Maybe you meant something like this, which iterates over the whole array and sums all even numbers. **Note that you need a pointer to int as the first Even_Sum parameter.**

Note also that the `i` parameter is useless in your code; in particular if it is meant to pass the number of elements in the array, you should not use it as an index variable. I've renamed it `n` and made the loop run from 0 to n-1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "evenSum.h"

int Even_Sum (int *array, int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum += array[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a `;` after the `int Even_Sum(int array, int i)` in your header file.

Without that `;` the compiler sees

```
int Even_Sum(int array, int i)

int Even_Sum(int array, int i)
{
    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {

... etc ...
```

This, of course, is not valid c syntax. Therefore, you need the `;`.

**Edit** as others pointed out, you want to work on the `int array` parameter since `array` is used as an *array of int* not as an *int*.

Comment: It's also not valid C since `array` is declared an int, not a pointer-to-int.

Comment: It also looks fishy because the parameter i is used as a loop counter instead of an array element number (hardcoded as 10).

Answer (score 0):

As a general debugging tip for messages like this, if you're getting errors (especially that "`expected ;`" one) at the start of your file then check the header file for typos. When you `#include` a header file it is like the compiler inserting the whole file into your file at that point, so errors on the first or second line hint to problems with the header file (since that's effectively "the line before").