# Value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c

I'm getting the following errors:

```
evenSum.c:9:11: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
   if(array[i] % 2 ==0)
       ^
evenSum.c:12:15: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
   sum += array[i];




   int Even_Sum(int array, int i)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            if(array[i] % 2 ==0)
            {
            int sum=0;
            sum += array[i];
            return sum;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: your variable named `array` is of type `int`. It is not an array of `int`s despite being named `array`.

Comment: `array[i]` you cannot do this to an int

Comment: which compiler is it?

Comment: in the main function 'int array' is an array.

Comment: @Mat I see. In TurboC, it gives `Invalid indirection` error, because `array[i]` implies `*(array+i)` and indirection `*` can be applied only to pointer

Comment: gcc's error message is a bit odd; the word "vector" here refers to a gcc-specific extension, not to C++'s `std::vector`.

Comment: @Mat it doesn't matter, the function `Even_Sum` still has it as `int`, not array. You could pass some int value to `Even_Sum` though

Comment: Way to much like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008076/sum-of-even-numbers-errors

Comment: Also, why are you passing `i` in as a function parameter, when you only use it as a local variable. Please revise how to declare and use function parameters, local variables in functions and stuff like that.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to read the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use it as an array it should be:

`int Even_Sum(int *array, int i)`

or

`int Even_Sum(int array[], int i)`

regardless of what you are trying to do in the rest of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, but now it does not + all the even numbers. It only prints the first even number as sum.

Comment: @Mat Well, you do `return` right after you found the first even number...

Comment: That's because you initilize `sum = 0` inside the loop, and you return the first even value. You should initilize `sum` outside the loop in the beginning of the function, and return its value after the loop ends.

Comment: Plus, you don't use the parameter `i`, you could just define it inside the function before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change the definition of `Even_Sum` to this:

```
int Even_Sum(int *array, int num)
{
    int i, sum;

    for(i = 0, sum = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        if(array[i] % 2 == 0)
            sum += array[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This would be a much more useful answer if you pointed out what exactly you changed, provided an explanation for the change(s).